# Combining a list of observations into one single variable in Stata

Tags: stata

I ran 500 simulations in Stata, i.e. I draw 500 samples, and each sample contains 10 observations. I want to generate a mean for each sample and combine all the 500 means into one variable, because I need to plot a histogram of the means. Currently I have 500 samples, named `X1`, `X2`, ... `X500`, where each `X` has 10 elements in it. I want to get a mean for each `X` and plot a histogram of the means. Can someone please show me how to do that? I tried to generate a new variable for the mean, i.e. `X1mean = mean(X1)`, but this wouldn't work, because all 10 empty elements would be filled with the mean.

Answer (score 1):

"Please tell me the code" questions are widely considered off-topic here. See  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic : "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

There are various ways to do this. One is to `collapse` and then `xpose` or `reshape long`. In fact, you could have produced a combined sample of 500 x 10 in the first place.

Another is to loop over variables like this

```
set obs 500 
gen mean = . 

quietly forval j = 1/500 { 
    su X`j', meanonly 
    replace mean = r(mean) in `j' 
} 

histogram mean
```

What you are presumably alluding to is code such as

```
egen X1mean = mean(X1)
```

That would be no use, but not for the reason you mention, as identical values can always be ignored: it would be no use because similar code would just produce 500 more variables. Note that `mean()` would not work with `generate` as `mean()` is an `egen` function.

The terminology you seek is observations, not elements.